# jquery .each() take image and title from a class and add each one to 5 diffrent div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I am stuck on this what I am trying to do is: there will be div's with the class of feature there could be an x amount of them but i only want 5 most resent. take the img src and a.html witch is a title link from each and add each one to 5 containing divs at the top of the page. the image as a background-image and the other prepend to an a tag. this is doing almost that but it takes the last image it finds and places that in each of the 5 containing divs and takes the title's it finds and also places each one in all 5 divs in other words its repeating when each containing div should be unique any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html body').find('.feature').each(function(e) {
        var post_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var post_title = $(this).find('a').html();

            $('.place_post_feature').each(function() {
                $(this).css({
                'backgroundImage': 'url(' + post_image + ')',
                'backgroundRepeat': 'no-repeat',
                'backgroundPosition': 'center',
                });

                $(this).find('a.preview').prepend(post_title);
            });//end each



    });//end find each
});//end ready
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try something like this, having a one to one correspondence between the place posts and features and terminating when you've reached your five posts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var placePosts = $('.place_post_feature');
        $('html body').find('.feature').each(function(index) {
            if (index < 5) {
                var post_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                var post_title = $(this).find('a').html();

                if (index < placePosts.length) {
                    $(placePosts[index]).css({
                        'backgroundImage': 'url(' + post_image + ')',
                        'backgroundRepeat': 'no-repeat',
                        'backgroundPosition': 'center'
                    });
                    $(placePosts[index]).find('a.preview').prepend(post_title);
                }
            }
        });//end find each
    });//end ready
</script>
```

Comment: Dead on shams!!! this works fantastically thank you so much for your help and I completely understand it now. My next step will be to incorporate this with Ajax, PHP and MySQL to be able to search more than one page and load dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The 5 divs you have across the top can only have one background image each, so when your script cycles through and adds a background image, it replaces the previous one. This is why you are ending up with only the last `.feature` showing.

So my question is, the 5 divs at the top should contain smaller divs with the background image and title? And please share some HTML so we can all get a better idea of what you need.